# ArcGIS Javascript API zoom out?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, zoom

I am using the ArcGIS API for Javascript and am wondering if it comes with functionality for zooming out using a rectangle, similar to the behavior in ArcGIS Desktop?  Specifically, the user draws a rectangle and it zooms out based on that rectangle.

I can create the functionality myself, but was wondering if it already existed in the API...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API has a [Navigation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/navigation-amd.html) toolbar class that uses this functionality.

It comes with a zoom out tool that works by drawing a box.

There is a sample page [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/toolbar_navigation.html).

Comment: Cool, thanks.  Do you know if I need to use their toolbar to get that functionality, or can I just use the functionality in my own UI?

Comment: Thanks.  I tinkered around and was able to use the navigation API without using any of the DOJO UI stuff.  Did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is [built into the API](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/navigation-amd.html). You just need to set up a navigation controller first:

```
navController = new esri.toolbars.navigation(yourMap)
navController.activate(Navigation.ZOOM_OUT);
```